# CardView Layout center position in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, cardview

Hey I develop my first Android Application and I struggle with my layout. I have a Carview in my Fragment and the layout is on each device on a other position.

I like to have the layout for each device (phones only) in a center position.

Pixel - Android 8.0 - 1080×1920 | 420 dpi

[image]

Mate 9 - Android 7.0 - 1080×1920 | 480 dpi

[image]

Galaxy J1 Ace - Android 5.1 - 480×800 | 240 dpi

[image]

Here is my CardView Code - I think my way is really strange - can somebody correct my layout and give me some advice how I can improve my "layout-skills"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_Image"
            android:layout_width="399dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/default_image_thumbnail"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="9dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_Usp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="9dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_below="@id/main_name"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/md_btn_time"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_time" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/md_btn_difficulty"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/md_btn_time"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/md_btn_time"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_difficulty" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/md_btn_servings"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/md_btn_difficulty"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/md_btn_difficulty"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_servings" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/md_btn_insta"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/md_btn_servings"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/md_btn_servings"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_insta" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/md_time"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="35 min"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/md_btn_time"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/md_difficulty"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/md_time"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/md_btn_time"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Leicht"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/md_servings"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/md_difficulty"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/md_btn_time"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/md_owner"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/md_servings"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/md_servings"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/md_btn_servings"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="self"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/main_Price"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="225dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/price_button"
                    android:text="12,99 €"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWithe"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You can use ConstraintLayout to achieve the same. Have you used ConstraintLayout yet?

Comment: Calculate your Linearlayout's height programmatically for different screen size.

Comment: This is a lot to do.Umangs is better.ConstraintLayout solves all such problems